# Convert mp4 to mpt with lower quality

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, mencoder

i need to convert videos from .mp4 to .mp4 (only videos that are disproportionate between quality and size), I've tried with ffmpeg and mencoder, but can not play with fwplayer, any ideas??.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Your question is not clear. Also show your ffmpeg command and complete console output. How else are we to know what is wrong? By fwplayer do you mean JW Player?

Answer (score 0):

Try using MeGUI, it has presets for low quality exporting for Flash and such.